# order of growth in algorithms

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Suppose that you time a program as a function of N and produce
the following table.

```
        N   seconds
-------------------
    19683      0.00
    59049      0.00
   177147      0.01
   531441      0.08
  1594323      0.44
  4782969      2.46
 14348907     13.58
 43046721     74.99
129140163    414.20
387420489   2287.85
```

Estimate the order of growth of the running time as a function of N.
Assume that the running time obeys a power law T(N) ~ a N^b. For your
answer, enter the constant b. Your answer will be marked as correct
if it is within 1% of the target answer - we recommend using
two digits after the decimal separator, e.g., 2.34.

Can someone explain how to calculate this?

Comment: Conceptually, take the log of the run-time, and then estimate the parameters of the resulting straight line.

Comment: Wasn't this explained in class? You need to read up on regression.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it is a simple mathematical problem.

```
I : a*387420489^b = 2287.85 -> a = 387420489^b/2287.85
II: a*43046721^b  =  74.99  -> a = 43046721^b/74.99
III: (I and II)-> 387420489^b/2287.85 = 43046721^b/74.99 ->
-> http://www.purplemath.com/modules/solvexpo2.htm
```

Use logarithms to solve.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "a = 2287.85/387420489"?

Answer (score 3):

1.You should calculate the ratio of the growth change from one row to the one next

```
N          seconds  
--------------------
14348907    13.58   
43046721    74.99   
129140163   414.2   
387420489   2287.85
```

2.Calculate the change's ratio for N

```
43046721 / 14348907 = 3
129140163 / 43046721 = 3
```

therefore the rate of change for N is 3.

3.Calculate the change's ratio for seconds

```
74.99 / 13.58 = 5.52
```

Now let check the ratio between one more pare of rows to be sure

```
414.2 / 74.99 = 5.52
```

so the change's ratio for seconds is 5.52

4.Build the following equitation

```
 3^b = 5.52
 b = 1.55
```

Finally we get that the order of growth of the running time is 1.55.